# PHP, How to fetch information from two different $post_id's within one loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a theme for a front page which displays the newest posts of my wordpress website.

I want to show with each post an image, (a advanced custom field from the post itself) and the author of the post (the title of a page which is linked to the post via advanced custom fields).

The code I have is:

```
    <?php 

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=12&offset=1' );


    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="article">

                <div class="articlepic">
                    <?php $image_obj = get_field('coverpic', $post_id ); if ( $image_obj ) : ?>
                        <img src="<?= $image_obj[ 'sizes' ]['small'] ?>">
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="articleabout">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    <br> 
                        <?php $post_id = get_field( 'author_link', false, false ); if( $post_id ): echo get_the_title( $post_id ); wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
                    <br>
                    Text about article.
                </div>

            </a>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

Both div's work fine independently, but when I add the second div (class="articleabout") the first div appears empty.

I suspect this could be because I add another $post_id in the second div which confuses the first div, but I dont know if that is in fact the problem or how I would fix that.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: So basically I am fetching the article post_id to display the image, and then fetching another post _id which is linked to that post_id to display the name of the author...

Comment: What happens when you remove the extra wp_reset_postdata() calls and only leave the last before the final end if?

Comment: I tried that before but nothing changes..

Comment: @Berglind you can get the author id from the post?

Comment: I've added an answer below - let me know if it works because I haven't been able to test because I don't have the setup as you (ACF fields etc) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are overwriting your loop data in the middle of your loop, which is breaking the loop.

You need to change 2 things -

1. You are overwriting the `$post_id` value with the post id for the author page. Just need to use another variable so your main post id isn't affected.
2. Remove the multiple `wp_reset_postdata` inside the loop (I'm not sure what that is meant to be doing?)

See the updated code below (note this isn't tested but the main idea is there):

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=12&offset=1' );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="article">

            <div class="articlepic">
                <?php $image_obj = get_field('coverpic', $post_id ); 
                 if ( $image_obj ) : ?>
                    <img src="<?= $image_obj[ 'sizes' ]['small'] ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="articleabout">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                <br> 
                <?php 
                 // DON'T USE YOUR POST_ID VARIABLE FOR THE AUTHOR PAGE!!
                 // Save it into a new variable
                 $author_post_id = get_field( 'author_link', false, false ); 
                 if( $author_post_id ): 
                      echo get_the_title( $author_post_id ); 
                 endif; ?>
                <br>
                Text about article.
            </div>

        </a>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

Comment: @Berglind Thats great, glad it worked when I hadn't been able to test it!